# Big O / strict/ partial order

Tags: order-theory

We define M as :={|:→ℝ+}
M
:=
{
f
|
f
:
n
→
R
+
}
 for ,∈
f
,
g
∈
M
 we say ≈,
 iff ∈Θ()
f
∈
Θ
(
g
)
. Since ≈
 is an equivalence relation (I have proved this part) we define the equivalence class []≈:={∈|≈}

Further we define 
⊳
 as a order relation between the classes and say: []≈⊳[]≈

iff ∈()

1) Prove or disprove whether ⊳ is a strict partial order?
 For ⊳
 to be a partial order, irreflexivity and transitivity have to fulfilled. []≈⊳[]≈

must NOT hold. However []≈⊳[]≈

equals ∈() which is fulfilled due to the symmetry of Big

.

So it can not be a strict partial order, right? How can I show that ⊳
 is a partial order? Reflexivity and transitivity are clear but how can I show antisymmetry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use the same notations as explained in the [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau-Symbole), then $f\in \theta(g)$ means

$$0 < \lim_{n\to\infty} \inf \left\lvert \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right\rvert \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \left\lvert \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right\rvert < \infty.$$

and $f\in O(g)$ means

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \left\lvert \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\right\rvert < \infty.$$

Now assume $[f] \rhd [g]$ and $[g] \rhd [f]$ (I've removed the $\approx$, because we are only dealing with one equivalence relation and using the "$[]$" brackets indicates that we are talking about the equivalence class of the function inside).

First, since all elements of $M$ are functions with co-domain $\mathbb R_+$, we can ignore the absolute values in the definitions above. So $[f] \rhd [g]$ and $[g] \rhd [f]$ mean

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < \infty \text{ and } \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \frac{g(n)}{f(n)} < \infty. \tag{1} \label{eq1}$$

Considering the second inequality, we have

$$\frac{g(n)}{f(n)} = \frac1{\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}}$$

and since $h(x)=\frac1x, h:\mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R_+$ is a monotonically **decreasing  continuous** function, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \frac{g(n)}{f(n)} = \frac1{\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf  \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}}.$$

The "decreasing" means we need to change from $\lim \sup$ to $\lim \inf$, and the "continuity" means those limits are the same. The right part of \eqref{eq1} says that the $\lim \sup$ on the left hand side above is finite (not $\infty$), so we know the $\lim \inf$ on the right hand side isn't $0$. Since $\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} > 0, \forall n$, that means

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \inf  \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} > 0. \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Now combining the left part of $\eqref{eq1}$ with $\eqref{eq2}$ we get

$$0 < \lim_{n\to\infty} \inf  \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup  \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < \infty.$$

where the middle "$\le$" is true for any sequence. This is however the definition of $f\in\theta(g)$ from the start of this answer, with the absolute values removed (as explained above).

So we have $f\in\theta(g)$ and hence $[f]=[g]$. That proves the antisymmetry of the partial order $\rhd$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer.

Comment: Just one additional question, if we first only want to disprove it being a strict partial order, does it suffice that we say that irreflexivity is not fulfiilled due to the reflexitivy property of $O$?

Comment: Yes, that works.